# how to take only first result from result list and set to a var?

Tags: windows, batch-file

writing a batch script to look for the right file.

```
dir /o:-d /a:-d F:\ | findstr /i ".target."
```

have the above script, my goal is to only the the very first file, and want to store the file name for for later script usage.

is there anyone know how can I get the first file, and set to a var?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example for retrieving the first line of your slightly modified command line, and save the line into a variable `line1`. The `/b` parameter is added onto `dir` command, since we only want the file name. The `|` character in the command line also needs to be escaped by a `^` character.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set line1=
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /o:-d /a:-d /b F:\ ^| findstr /i ".target."') do (
  set line1=%%A
  rem exit loop immediately once we got the line
  goto next
)
:next
if "%line1%" != "" (
  echo First Line:
  echo %line1%
) else (
  echo No file is found
)
```